# SQL- do any number ranges overlap

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has a list of number ranges. I need to know if any of these number ranges overlap eachother

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df30c)

Example, the last 2 rows in the fiddle overlap eachother. I'm not sure how you would even show that in a query result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Not sure if this would work but appears to be:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    FROM_NUM,
    TO_NUM,
    LEAD(FROM_NUM) OVER (ORDER BY FROM_NUM) A
  FROM
    RANGES
) RANGES
WHERE
  A < TO_NUM
```

Comment: Isn't technically `INSERT INTO RANGES VALUES (2501,2501)` overlapping too?

Comment: They overlap with eachother but not other rows so I'm not concerned about these.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RANGES.FROM_NUM AS BASE_FROM_NUM,  RANGES.TO_NUM AS BASE_TO_NUM,
  OVERLAP.FROM_NUM AS OVERLAP_FROM_NUM, OVERLAP.TO_NUM AS OVERLAP_TO_NUM
FROM RANGES
INNER JOIN RANGES OVERLAP 
ON (((OVERLAP.FROM_NUM <= RANGES.FROM_NUM) AND (OVERLAP.TO_NUM >= RANGES.FROM_NUM))
OR ((OVERLAP.FROM_NUM <= RANGES.TO_NUM) AND (OVERLAP.TO_NUM >= RANGES.TO_NUM)))
AND ((OVERLAP.FROM_NUM <> RANGES.FROM_NUM) AND (OVERLAP.TO_NUM <> RANGES.TO_NUM))
```

The last line is only to stop rows reporting overlaps for themselves. In practice, you would remove them by using a unique key (just in case you have duplicate rows with the same from/to numbers):

```
AND (OVERLAP.ID <> RANGES.ID)
```